# pg_restore: [compress_io] could not uncompress data: invalid code lengths set

Tags: database, postgresql, zlib, dump, pg-restore

I've had problems to execute `pg_restore`command in Mac.
It's returning this error:

```
pg_restore: [compress_io] could not uncompress data: invalid code lengths set
```

I'm using postgres 9.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error message comes from the [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) library used by PostgreSQL for compression.

I'd say that the file probably got corrupted (ASCII file transfer?).

Comment: You're right, man!
I downloaded again the file and it's working now.

Thanks ;)